# Can I merge a Facebook company page and an application?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I already have a page for my company that has more than 240 friends. On the other hand I recently started to develop a Facebook App (that has the same name) to use the Graph API from my company's website. The problem is that I don't want to lose my fans nor start again ads campaign, etc. Is there any way to merge those two or make a Facebook App from the company's page (ie: using the same ID?) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regular Page and Application Page, are very different with some similar features and similar look but different functionality and goals, ensure you really want this switch at all...

Answer (score 2):

This is technically possible, but it won't work the way you want it to — a bug has been filed on this with Facebook, and is [located here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/375929795795274?browse=search_5057d2cd2546a0d33494358). Perhaps if enough of us file repros on the bug it will get some attention from Facebook.

Here's the story:

You can make a new page for the App, according to the instructions [here, near the bottom of the page:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)

> Simply visit the Contact Info section in the App Details tab of the
>   App Dashboard, and click on the “Create Facebook Page” button to
>   create a new Facebook Page.

That new page will be associated with the App ID you're already using.

And then that page can be merged, according to the instructions linked to in Juicy Scripter's answer. (Basically, you need to make the names as identical as possible and then request the merge from the "Resources" section of the page admin area.)

*However*, then you will be merging *into* the page with the higher number of likes. And, as I discovered by testing this with a newly created page-from-an-app and a existing page with 3k+ likes, merging an app-linked page with a regular page works, but the app is no longer linked to the resulting merged page.

So while I can't test it, the only possible fix left, short of Facebook supporting the functionality directly, would be (1) create a new page from your existing app; (2) recruit more likes to that new page than currently exist on your old page; (3) **then** request a merge.

Maybe if you're merging into the page that's associated with the app, that association will survive the merge.

If anyone can cast more light on this, it would be great to have a way to do this. I trust I'm not the only newbie webmaster who created an App ID for social plugins, Facebook-based comments, etc. and separately created a page to promote the website on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like something to ask facebook personel.
I'm also pretty sure facebook dislikes companies having standard profiles instead of company pages wich can be 'liked'(not friended), you might want to consider that too.

Comment: I didn't mentioned a standard profile at all. I was talking about a regular company page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My apologies, i was confused with the fact that your company page has 240 friends. i thought company pages did not have the ability to have friends, that's why i presumed you were using a regular profile.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no way to merge Facebook's Pages, nor transferring fans from one to other in automated manner.</strike>

The only option you have is publishing updates to fans of your page informing 'em with availability of new Application and providing information how to switch (and probably reason why to do this).

**Update:**
There is no Application Profile Pages anymore (they are deprecated as of 1st Feb 2012, see [official blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/)).

As for regular Facebook pages, pages now can be merged and this process outlined in Help Center, see [I have two Facebook Pages for the same thing. Can I merge them?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018).

Comment: Thank you, that's the reply I was expecting, unfortunately :)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem as the original question, but this response is wrong, you can merge Facebook pages http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018

Comment: @JonVaughan, answer wasn't updated to represent current state of functionality provided on subject. Thanks for pointing with exact link to Help Center, updated answer. (BTW, original question was about Application Profile Page functionality which is no longer exists and replaced by regular pages associated with applications)

Answer (score 1):

So we first created a page for our website [www.fantasyplanet.de](http://www.fantasyplanet.de) on facebook and later realized that we want to have a social login, which is only possible with a facebook app. Without thinking to much about it we created an app to enable the login, but how to join them later together?

Go to developer dashboard.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

Select your App and go to.

```
Settings > Advanced > App Page
```

Create **a new page**. Just skip through the whole creation process and create the page. Now we will **merge** the old and the new page.

```
www.facebook.com/pages/merge
```

Select the new and the old pages you want to merge, the process here is explained well while you click through. Just pay attention not to overwrite your new page.